# Adaptive Search Boost Rules

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

If smb could help me to understand Adaptive Search Boost Rules mechanism? Or give some notes to read. The main problem that after adding boost rule it's added to searchQuery with no problems, but in final query there are no any boost? What should I do to add it to query?

`{!edismax tie=0.0}(( (masterBrandNameSearchText_text_nl_be:armani)^1  (masterBrandNameSearchText_text_nl_be:armani*)^0.2  (masterBrandNameSearchText_text_nl_be:*armani)^0.2  (masterBrandNameSearchText_text_nl_be:armani~0.7 )^0.1  ((masterBrandNameSearchText_text_nl_be_st:armani)^1)^0.5)^30`

[image]

I have no idea what way is right to add this boost

Am I right that those boost rule should be added to final query?

Comment: note: boost tag is for C++ library

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that on our project **LegacyFacetSearchStrategy** was used implicitly.
So the functions of **Adaptive Search** were presented, but were not worked as well.

To solve the problem we added additional query on the last step of building the query. As we were used eDisMax qParser template was as:

```
{!edismax tie=0.0}defaultQuery    
boost=product(query((field:value)^00)) - field, value, boostFactor - params were taken from boost rule
```